# ADFS 3.0 - Redirecting user to another page

Tags: adfs3.0

I have ADFS server and proxy server installed and few Relying party trusts added to it for sso.It is SP initiated and it all works fine. I have restricted access to a AD group for one of the RP site. When non-member of the group tries to access the site using the SP initiated URL, it gives an error (Missing SAML attributes). When logs checked, it is found that for the non-group members claim value is passed as "nil". Is there any way we can redirect the unauthorised user to another page or simply displaying an error like " YOu are not allowed access".

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show some code that you've tried so far.

Comment: I did a few settings in the claims rule in "Issusance Authorization rules" tab.  Permit and deny users based on incoming claim-- group SID(incoming claim type )-- group name (incoming claim value)-- finish. that's all I have done

Answer (score 0):

If ADFS is configured to pass groups as Roles, then use [IsInRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) and use that to redirect to an error message.

**Update:**

This can be done by adding a so-called [Issuance Authorization Rule](https://serverfault.com/questions/676916/adfs-restrict-to-ad-group).

Essentially:

- Go to the Issuance Authorization Rules tab
- Delete the default Permit Access To All Users rule
- Click Add Rule
- Select Permit or Deny Users Based on an Incoming Claim

Comment: Thanks for your help. But where do I write this code? I have access only to IDP side not to SP side.

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing.  but it gives error for the non-members of the group "missing SAML response". The vendor says- "u gota redirect ADFS to a error message for non-members." What could be done now?